# Docker: shell file "does not exist" when it blatantly does

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a Docker container to run a shell script as its entry point.

Here's my (simple) Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.102 as base
WORKDIR /tests

COPY . .

RUN dotnet build -c Release

ARG CHECKSERVICES
ENV CHECKSERVICES ${CHECKSERVICES}

RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

But if I run this container I get the following output:

```
endtoendtests_1  | sh: 1: ./entrypoint.sh: not found
```

That's odd, I thought. I'm pretty sure I've got the path correct. Sure enough, if I change the `entrypoint` declaration in the Dockerfile to `ls` I get this output:

```
endtoendtests_1  | Backdoor
endtoendtests_1  | Context
endtoendtests_1  | Dockerfile
endtoendtests_1  | Dtos
endtoendtests_1  | Features
endtoendtests_1  | Hooks.cs
endtoendtests_1  | Http.EndToEndTests.csproj
endtoendtests_1  | Ioc.cs
endtoendtests_1  | Izberg
endtoendtests_1  | IzbergStubAddressIds.cs
endtoendtests_1  | IzbergStubShippingOptionsIds.cs
endtoendtests_1  | IzbergStubUserIds.cs
endtoendtests_1  | Repository
endtoendtests_1  | Steps
endtoendtests_1  | Utils
endtoendtests_1  | appsettings.json
endtoendtests_1  | bin
endtoendtests_1  | entrypoint.sh  <--------------- There you are!
endtoendtests_1  | obj
```

in which `entrypoint.sh` is clearly visible. So why do I get "file not found" when I try to execute it?

Note: I'm running this container as part of a docker-compose setup, if that's significant.

Comment: Did your `ls` test look like: `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "ls"]`?

Comment: No, just `ENTRYPOINT ["ls"]`

Comment: What's the first line of the `entrypoint.sh` script; does that interpreter exist in the image?  Are you mounting something over the `/tests` directory in your `docker-compose.yml` file?  If you're on a Windows host, have you double-checked the script's line endings?

Comment: Ok, try to make the test as similar to the real thing as possible. Also, `sh` may be interpreted as old bourne shell. If you have `bash`-code in the script, it could probably fail with `not found`. In that case: `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "./entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, so changing the entrypoint to explicitly bash gives this: `endtoendtests_1  | bash: ./entrypoint.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: Looks like you have Windows line endings in the file. Is the first line in `entrypoint.sh` `#!/bin/sh`? `dos2unix entrypoint.sh` might help.

Comment: It is; I will change the line endings and try again

Comment: OMG it worked! It turned out to be the bloomin' line endings! Feel free to write that up as an answer and I'll select it as the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./entrypoint.sh: not found` may be caused by the interpreter on line 1 not being found.

This can happen if you for example have Windows line endings in the script while running in a unix environment.

Try: `dos2unix entrypoint.sh`